# RegEx - Excluding pattern from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this string: (Don't mind the double quotes)

```
<img alt=""Thanks StackOverflow users <3"" class=""xxx"" src=""xxx"" width=""xxx"" />
```

I need to select **anything except** the inner text of the **alt attribute**.

I came up with this solution but essentialy i need to do the **exact opposite** but i can't get it to work:

```
(?<=alt="")(.*?)(?<="")
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve here? *Matching* approach is exactly what you need given the current question context. ECMAScript regex has no way to match any text other than a particular multicharacter matching pattern, though workarounds are possible, and that depends on exact case.

Comment: You can `.replace(/alt=""[^"]""/, '')`. It creates a copy without the `alt` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can `.replace(/alt=""[^"]""/, 'alt=""""')`. It creates a copy without the `alt` attribute

```js
const text = '<img alt=""Thanks StackOverflow users <3"" class=""xxx"" src=""xxx"" width=""xxx"" />';

const result = text.replace(/alt=""[^"]+""/, 'alt=""""');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way might just be to use two capturing groups to get what you want, and another non-capturing group to get what you want to exclude. Here would be an example:

- [`(.+alt="")(?:.*?)("".*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Pl0ibk/1)

[image]

Alternately, you can select what you do want to exclude and replace it, which is the other answer. I'd suggest that approach.